# Generating all equal-sized set partitions

Tags: algorithms, enumeration

Minor disclaimer: This is my first question here, so I hope it is the 
right place to put it.

---

Question: Is there an algorithm to exhaustively generate all set 
partitions of equal size? That is, I want to list all possible ways to 
divide a set of $N$ elements into $K$ parts where each part has the same 
size $\frac{N}{K}$. At best, I want to generate all of these partitions 
sequentially without generating any duplicates. There are many 
algorithms to list all divisions of a set into $K$ parts that however do 
not impose a size constraint on the parts. But I have not found anything 
on generating set partitions of equal size.

I assume that the elements in the set are labeled using labels $1, ..., 
K$. For $K = 2$ groups, I can exhaustively list all partitions by 
sequentially generating all permutations of the group labels in 
lexicographic order and stop as soon as the first element is $2$ [that 
is assuming I started with the initial partition $(1, 1, 1, ...., 2, 2, 
2)$]. However, for $K > 3$ generating permutations of the labels does 
work anymore without generating duplicate partitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $N=\{0,\dots,N-1\}$.
There are $\binom{N-1}{K-1}$ choices for which elements are equivalent to 0. For each choice of these there are $\binom{N-K-1}{K-1}$ choices for which elements are equivalent to the smallest number not equivalent to 0. And then $\binom{N-2K-1}{K-1}$ for which elements are equivalent to the smallest number not equivalent to any number chosen so far. 
Continuing to iterate this way, we get through all the $\prod_{a=0}^{N/K-1}\binom{N-aK-1}{K-1}$ balanced partitions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this response; I think I will have to "digest" it a bit before accepting the answer (will try to implement it to better understand what you mean). Do you by any chance have a reference for your method or did you just come up with?

Comment: I just came up with it but it's probably/surely been done before

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask for a clarification: What do you exactly mean by "choice"? Selecting one possible partition? In this case, what would it mean that elements in this choice are equivalent to 0?

Comment: Yes, and equivalent to 0 means: in the same part as 0.

Comment: ah I see, thanks a lot!